# Job y runner siempre aparecen bloqueados Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, jobs

Dese que cree el primer job de prueba, su estado siempre es "stuck", luego me di cuenta que necesitaba un "runner" y instalé uno en el proyecto de Gitlab. Escogí el más adecuado a al job que estoy utilizando (es meramente una prueba y un solo comando para shell).

Nada más crear el runner, su estado el locked. Entiendo que es "bloqueado" pero no entiendo realmente porqué lo está.

Igualmente he ido haciendo commits de pruebas, y el job es lanzado pero siempre bloqueado, nunca llego a ver nada por consola y solo hago un "hellow world" a la shell.

**version gitlab: GitLab Enterprise Edition 10.3.3-ee.**

**version gitlab-runner: 10.3.0.**

Mi código del gitlab-ci.yml es:

```
before_script:
  - echo "echo 'hola" | /bin/bash --login
  - echo "echo 'Paco" | /bin/bash --login
#test

stages:
    - test

job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - bash echo 'hellow world'

  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - runner
    - testPrimerJob
```

Comment: ¿Solucionaste este problema? Veo que tocas bastante GitLab